# Row level filtering with Data Studio and BigQuery - Sharing the dashboard with external users

Tags: looker-studio

In order to create external users data-studio dashboard using row level premissions method I followed the instructions here: https://developers.google.com/datastudio/solution/row-level-filtering.

Everything is working fine ,until I got to the sharing part:

[Make the dashboard available to users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lawQw.png)

In order to share the dashboard with external users I need to share the connector script.

Is there a better & safer way to share the dashboard with exteranl users using row level premission method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ability to [Filter by email address](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9713766) (Provide row-level security to the data for signed-in users) was released today (13 Feb 2020).

Quoting the steps from the support page:

> **Create an email filter**
>    1. Edit your data source.
>    2. In the upper left, click FILTER BY EMAIL.
>    3. Turn on Filter data by viewer email.
>    4. Select the field in your data source that contains viewer email addresses.
>    5. To return to the data source editor, click ALL FIELDS.